# 8086 qemu my own keyboard interrupt handler

Tags: keyboard, qemu, x86-16

I am trying to write a bootloader which is just a program that sets its own keybord interrupt handler and handles keyboard presses.
However I am lost.

This one does not respond to keyboard presses by writing to video RAM.

```
 org 7c00h ; BOOT PROGRAM

            mov ax,03h
            int 10h ; 80x25 video mode
            mov ax,1112h;
            int 10h ; 80x50 video mode



            cli ; Zakaz preruseni
            mov word[ds:20h],keyboard_handler ; nastaveni INT9 na moji funkci
            mov word[ds:22h],0h         
            sti

            jmp $

keyboard_handler:
            cli
            push ax
            push dx
            push bx

            in al,60h

            mov dx,0b800h
            mov es,dx
            mov dx,0000h
            mov ds,dx

            mov dl,10h
            div dl; al+ah
            add ax,3030h

            mov dl,ah

            cmp al,3ah
            jl not_add 
            add al,7h
not_add     cmp dl,3ah  
            jl not_add2
            add dl,7h

not_add2    mov ah,21h
            mov dh,21h

            mov bx,[ds:vidoff]

            mov word[es:bx],ax
            add bx,2h
            mov word[es:bx],dx
            add bx,2h

            mov word[ds:vidoff],bx


            ;finalizing code
            mov al,20h
            out 20h,al ;odhlaseni preruseni

            ;mov word ax,[ds:22h]
            ;mov cs,ax
            ;mov ds,ax
            ;mov ss,ax
            ;mov es,ax

            pop bx
            pop dx
            pop ax
            sti
            iret

 vidoff dw 0FF0h 

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h
```

And this one is messy, but it keeps writing to video RAM eventhough no key was pressed. If I press a key, however, at least it responds to my keypress by taking my scancode and writing to video RAM accordingly. Then it again continues as if some key was pressed continously.

```
org 7c00h ; BOOT PROGRAM

            ;++++++ Nastaveni video mode 80x50 a INT9(co reaguje na klavesnici pomoci preruseni IRQ1)
            mov ax,03h
            int 10h ; 80x25 video mode
            mov ax,1112h;
            int 10h ; 80x50 video mode

            mov dx,0b800h
            mov es,dx
            mov dx,0h
            mov ds,dx   

            mov di,0FF0h

            mov bx,0h
            mov ds,bx
            cli ; Zakaz preruseni
            mov word[ds:20h],keyboard_handler ; nastaveni INT9 na moji funkci
            mov word[ds:22h],0h         
            sti
                    ; Povoleni preruseni
            jmp $

keyboard_handler:   
            push es
            push ax
            mov ax,0h
            in al,60h           

            mov ch,10h
            div ch
            mov byte[prvni_cislice],al
            mov byte[druha_cislice],ah

            mov ch,al
            mov cl,0dbh
            mov word[barva_cislice],cx

            mov bl,ah
            mov bh,0dbh
            cmp cx,bx
            jne normal 
            xor ch,0fh
            mov bh,ch
normal      mov word[barva_podkladu],bx

            mov word[es:di],bx
            add di,2h

            mov al,20h
            out 20h,al ;odhlaseni preruseni

            pop ax
            pop es
            iret


;hexacislice            
prvni_cislice db 0h
druha_cislice db 0h 

;hotove znaky
barva_podkladu dw 0h
barva_cislice dw 0h

offset_radku dw 0h

PRNGseed dw 0h

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h
```

What I am doing wrong? Am I forgetting something? In some other code I saw somebody adding out,61h or something like that, I dont know what that does though.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with these programs is that you are NOT setting up the keyboard interrupt! Instead you are messing with the system timer interrupt.

```
mov word[ds:20h],keyboard_handler ; nastaveni INT9 na moji funkci
mov word[ds:22h],0h
```

Better use this :

```
mov word[ds:24h],keyboard_handler
mov word[ds:26h],0h
```

The rest of the code you've written poses a real challenge to people that do not speak your native language. Please use English-only names for labels and variables.
Also be generous with comments in your code. They make reading a lot easier and thus increase your chance of getting an answer.